# Merging DeepPartial / DeepMerge / Confine generic

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a rather complicated generic. I've asked many questions on StackOverflow to try and piece meal what I want so I thought I'd just explain what I am looking for.

Given an interface:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  address: {
    line1: string,
    line2: string | null | number,
    zip: string | number,
    address: {
      line1: string,
      line2: string | null | number,
      zip: string | number,
    } | string,
  },
};
```

I am looking for a way to be able to create another interface from this interface that is limits some of it's scope while copying some of it over.

### Examples

For instance I would like to have the ability to

- limit `Person.address.address` to a just string

```
type PersonEdit = {
  address: {
    address: string,
  },
};
```

- limit `Person.address.address` to a just an object

```
type PersonEdit = {
  address: {
    address: {},
  },
};
```

- change any property to optional,

```
type PersonEdit = {
  address: {
    address?: {} | string,
  },
};
```

- limit `Person.address.address.zip` to just a number

```
type PersonEdit = {
  address: {
    address: {
      zip: number
    },
  },
};
```

### Requirements

- I would like to be able to just focus on the nested property and inherit all of the other types from the rest of the interface.
- These `Edits` should be a `DeepPartial<>` of the source and not allow new properties or unions that aren't in the parent.

### Existing generics

Here's what the great folks on StackOverflow have helped me come up with so far from other questions i've asked.

```
type Confine<A, B extends { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : never }> = B;
```

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends (infer U)[]
  ? DeepPartial<U>[]
  : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
      ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<U>>
      : DeepPartial<T[P]>
};
```

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = T extends any ? U extends any ?
  [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U : never : never;
```

### Update

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = T extends any ? U extends DeepPartial<T> ?
  [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U : never : never;
```

This works well but does not confine `U` to not add any new properties.